# What is the 'cart' being referred to?

Tags: barbie-2023

The Mattel CEO fainted upon hearing from Aaron, a Mattel
representative, that life-size versions of Barbie dolls were
coming to Los Angeles from Barbie Land to roam the earth:

> Mattel CEO : Ahh! Ahh! No.

Men trying to help Mattel CEO:

> Man 1: Get the chair!
>
> Man 2: Take **the cart**.

[image]

I don't see any carts in the scene.

What is the 'cart' being referred to?

Comment: If the line is “_get_ the cart” it would be referring to a [crash cart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_cart), presumably

Comment: How sure are you of the transcription there? Can you link us to the scene or the script to check? I can't find anything resembling that dialog here: https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/barbie-2023.pdf

Comment: @terdon - I'm looking at the Closed Captions and the dialogue seems accurate. They're almost certainly ad-libbing though. I think Fez is right that this was supposed to be "Take  the chair, get the (crash) cart" and got reversed in editing.

Comment: I agree it is ad-libbed, @Valorum, since the scene is completely different in the few versions of the script I found online. But in that case, who knows what was said? Could have been "Fake the dart" or "check the heart" or whatever :/